# How do I send an email using Google App Scripts as a pdf with a python script?

Tags: javascript, python, excel

So I'm trying to make an invoice app where by entering a few details into the app, it'll automatically create a new sheet on a Google Sheet, update values, and send that particular sheet as a pdf via email.

I have finished the Python app, however I could not find any modules that can email a google sheet as a pdf directly. That's when I stumbled across Google App Scripts where you can use js to create a trigger function on the google sheet. Ive set it up but whenever I enter "use  the app", the google script sends 3 emails instead of 1. Tbh I only want to send an email once the new created sheet has been update, but I cannot find a way to do that yet.

I tried using the onEdit() simple trigger, but that trigger does not support sending emails, so ive been forced to use the installable trigger. However, through a bit of testing i found that if I try to to use the onEdit installable trigger in conjunction with my python script, it doesn't "count" as an edit, but a change instead. So i was forced to use the onChange installable trigger.
Here's the code:

app script:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  console.log(sheet.getName())// check what the active sheet is
  

    if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(33, 5).getValue() > 0) //if (row=33, col=5) (final price) > 0, execute 
    {
      console.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(33, 5).getValue())//testing to see what value is in this cell ('E33')
      var message = {
      to: "myemail@gmail.com",
      subject: "Monthly sales report",
      body: "Hi team,\n\nPlease find the monthly report attached.\n\nThank you,\nBob",
      name: "Bob",
      attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Monthly sales report")]
    }
    console.log(message);
    // MailApp.sendEmail(message);

    }
    else
    { }
  }
```

python script:

```
import gspread
from gspread_formatting import *
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from tkinter import *  # for gui

# tkinter 2 step process: Create widget, display widget

root = Tk()  # necessary for any gui

qty = []
desc = []
unit = []

canvas = Canvas(root, width=800, heigh=500)
canvas.pack()
frame = Frame(root, bg='#FFFF00')
quantityListbox = Listbox(frame)
descriptionListbox = Listbox(frame)
unitListbox = Listbox(frame)
quantityTextbox = Text(frame)
descriptionTextbox = Text(frame)
unitTextbox = Text(frame)


# NOTE: 'template' sheet is the invoice template

def sendToSheet(company, invNum, orderNum, job, date, address):
    scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sprea...",
             "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive...", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
    print('Sending')
    ##initialises stuff
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("credentials.json")
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)

    ##everything below here rn is making the invoice template
    spreadsheet = client.open("InvoiceMe")  # opens spread sheet

    sst = spreadsheet.worksheet('template')  # opens up worksheet 1

    sst.duplicate(new_sheet_name=company)  # duplicates "template" and renames the new sheet

    currentss = spreadsheet.worksheet(company)  # gets/opens work sheet with name as parameter

    # update cells
    currentss.update('E11', invNum)
    currentss.update('E12', orderNum)
    currentss.update('E13', job)
    currentss.update('E14', date)
    currentss.update('C17', company)
    currentss.update('C18', address)

    ###updates quantity + amount
    for i, item in enumerate(qty):
        # print('B' + str(22 + i))
        currentss.update('B' + str(22 + i), item)
        # currentss.update('E' + str(22 + i), '=B' + str(22 + i) + '*' + 'D' + str(22 + i))

    ###udpates description
    for i, item in enumerate(desc):
        # print('B' + str(22 + i))
        currentss.update('C' + str(22 + i), item)

    #updates unit
    for i, item in enumerate(unit):
        # print('B' + str(22 + i))
        currentss.update('D' + str(22 + i), item)



    print('Invoice updated')


###adds values to global list
def addToList(q, d, u):  # qty, desc, unit
    global qty, desc, unit
    qty.append(q)
    quantityListbox.insert(END, q)
    print(qty)  # test purposes
    quantityTextbox.delete('1.0', END)

    desc.append(d)
    descriptionListbox.insert(END, d)
    print(desc)  # test purposes
    descriptionTextbox.delete('1.0', END)

    unit.append(u)
    unitListbox.insert(END, '$' + u)
    print(unit)  # test purposes
    unitTextbox.delete('1.0', END)




def gui():
    global frame, quantityListbox, descriptionListbox, unitListbox, \
        quantityTextbox, descriptionTextbox, unitTextbox

    frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    titleLabel = Label(frame, text='InvoiceMe')
    titleLabel.place(anchor='n', relx=0.5, rely=0.02)

    # company
    companyLabel = Label(frame, text='To/Company')
    companyLabel.place(anchor='n', relx=0.18, rely=0.1)

    companyTextBox = Text(frame)
    companyTextBox.place(anchor='n', relx=0.18, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.05)

    # address
    addressLabel = Label(frame, text='Address')
    addressLabel.place(anchor='n', relx=0.55, rely=0.1)

    addressTextBox = Text(frame)
    addressTextBox.place(anchor='n', relx=0.55, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.05)

    # date
    dateLabel = Label(frame, text='Date')
    dateLabel.place(anchor='n', relx=0.85, rely=0.1)

    dateTextbox = Text(frame)
    dateTextbox.place(anchor='n', relx=0.85, rely=0.15, relwidth=0.20, relheight=0.05)

    # invoice number
    invoiceLabel = Label(frame, text='Invoice number')
    invoiceLabel.place(anchor='n', relx=0.85, rely=0.3)

    invoiceTextbox = Text(frame)
    invoiceTextbox.place(anchor='n', relx=0.85, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.20, relheight=0.05)

    # order num
    orderLabel = Label(frame, text='Order number')
    orderLabel.place(anchor='n', relx=0.85, rely=0.45)

    orderTextbox = Text(frame)
    orderTextbox.place(anchor='n', relx=0.85, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.20, relheight=0.05)

    # job num
    jobLabel = Label(frame, text='Job')
    jobLabel.place(anchor='n', relx=0.85, rely=0.6)

    jobTextbox = Text(frame)
    jobTextbox.place(anchor='n', relx=0.85, rely=0.65, relwidth=0.20, relheight=0.05)

    # submit button
    submit = Button(frame, text='Send Invoice', command=lambda: sendToSheet(companyTextBox.get('1.0', 'end'),
                                                                            invoiceTextbox.get('1.0', 'end'),
                                                                            orderTextbox.get('1.0', 'end'),
                                                                            jobTextbox.get('1.0', 'end'),
                                                                            dateTextbox.get('1.0', 'end'),
                                                                            addressTextBox.get('1.0', 'end')))
    submit.place(anchor='n', relx=0.85, rely=0.8, relwidth=0.15, relheight=0.1)

    quantityLabel = Label(frame, text='Quantity')
    quantityLabel.place(anchor='n', relx=0.11, rely=0.3)

    quantityTextbox.place(anchor='n', relx=0.11, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.05)

    quantityListbox.place(anchor='n', relx=0.11, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.4)

    descriptionLabel = Label(frame, text='Description')
    descriptionLabel.place(anchor='n', relx=0.36, rely=0.3)

    descriptionTextbox.place(anchor='n', relx=0.36, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.05)

    descriptionListbox.place(anchor='n', relx=0.36, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.35, relheight=0.4)

    unitLabel = Label(frame, text='Unit')
    unitLabel.place(anchor='n', relx=0.61, rely=0.3)

    unitTextbox.place(anchor='n', relx=0.61, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.05)

    unitListbox.place(anchor='n', relx=0.61, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.4)

    addButton = Button(frame, text='add', command=lambda: addToList(quantityTextbox.get('1.0', 'end-1c'),
                                                                    descriptionTextbox.get('1.0', 'end-1c'),
                                                                    unitTextbox.get('1.0', 'end-1c')))
    addButton.place(anchor='n', relx=0.61, rely=0.425, relwidth=0.075, relheight=0.05)


# sendToSheet(company, invNum, orderNum, job, date, address):

gui()

root.mainloop()  # necessarry for gui
```

I should probably point out that I am new to python, and was looking for a project and this is what I decided to do. treat me as if i were a noob and any pointers will be appreciated :)